# Sum to 5 is greater than the Sum to infinity. How is this possible?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

I've reached the correct answer but I don't see how the sum of the first 5 terms in the following geometric sequence is greater than the sum to infinity:

$$a= 9, \, r= \frac{-1}{3}$$

Given: Sum to infinity = 6.75

$S_5=\frac{(9(1-(-1/5)^5))}{4/3} = 6.78$,  using $S_n=\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$

Could it be simply because the sum to infinity will continue to increase marginally?

Thanks in advance,

Matt.

Comment: Look at what each consecutive PAIR of numbers is adding to the overall sum

Comment: I got $$\frac{61}{9}$$ in your formula!

Comment: It must be $$(-\frac{1}{3})^5$$

Answer (score 3):

When the terms are positive the sum up to $n$ terms keeps increasing with $n$ so the sum of first five terms has to be less than the sum to $\infty$. But when you have positive and negative terms there is absolutely no reason why sum of first five terms has to be less than the sum to $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification everyone.